# How does IN SQL looks in C# linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How does IN SQL looks in C# linq, Have tried

```
SELECT * FROM ACON.ProductData.LngText Where LngCod='SWE' 
AND TextId IN (SELECT DISTINCT [AlfCod]      
FROM [ACON].[Measure].[RatedCurrent])
```

This

```
from l in LngTexts
where l.LngCod=="swe" && 
l.TextId.Contains((from m in Measure_RatedCurrents
select m.AlfCod).Distinct())
select l
```

Dosn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Contains` on the result of inner query:

```
from l in LngTexts
where l.LngCod=="swe" && 
   (from m in Measure_RatedCurrents
    select m.AlfCod).Distinct().Contains(l.TextId)
select l
```

Comment: Works if one removes one of the parentheses after the Distinct